# Add a value to use within a scope in C# dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have .NET 6 applications that are handling messages from a service bus. When these classes handle a message, I will need to take details from that message and have the available into a service registered at application startup.

```
//app startup
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<MyConsumer>();
services.AddScoped<MyService>();
services.AddScoped<MyRepository>();
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var consumer = sp.GetService<MyConsumer>();


public class MyUserInfo
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(MyRepository repo) { _repo = repo; }
    public object GetRecord(long id)
    {
        var res = _repo.Find(id);
        if(res is null)
            throw new Exception("Unauthorized!");
        return res;
    }
}

public class MyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(MyUserInfo user) { _user = user; }
    public object Find(id)
    {
        //ALWAYS filter the data to only what the user should access for security
        var query = _db.Set<MyObj>()
            .Where(x => x.UserId = _user.UserId);
            
        return query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

//consumer
public class MyConsumer
{
    public MyConsumer(IServiceProvider sp) { _sp = sp; }

    //this is called by external code to handle a message
    public void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {
        var userInfo = new MyUserInfo { UserId = myMessage.UserId };
        using var scope = _sp.CreateScope();

        //todo: i want to register this userInfo to be used only within the scope i'm in now
        //e.g. scope.AddScoped(userInfo);

        var myService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
        var record = _myService.GetRecord(message.RecordId);
        //now perform some action associated with this consumer... etc
    }
}
```

Does what I'm asking make sense? In this situation I want to the consumer to act similarly to how a .NET web app works- I create a single service provider, and then during the scope of a "request" (message), I want that request-specific data to be available as scoped, so that when i resolve the scoped `MyService`, i will get the `userInfo` defined from the request.

Is there any way to do this ?

The only alternative I've found so far is to make a new `ServiceProvider` on every request which is not ideal:

```
public void Handle(MyMessage message)
{
    var userInfo = new MyUserInfo { UserId = myMessage.UserId };
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddScoped<MyService>();
    services.AddScoped<MyRepository>();
    services.AddScoped(userInfo);
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Comment: What would be the benefit or for what benefit you are hoping for here compared to a simple Transient MyService?

Comment: The benefit is that deep in the stack of registrations, i want to be able to register other services as scoped that depend on the current user. this is what i can do for asp.net apps. so if i can't do that for a console application, i'd have to refactor my entire codebase to allow me to pass the userid down to every component that might need it, because it can't be resolved from the serviceprovider.

Comment: @Ralf i updated the question to show a more real-world like example of how i would use this. I want to register my user information so that i can use it in a child service down the line.
i also provided a counter example of how i have to do this now- where i have to recreate the entire serviceprovider on every request which is wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the way you want to do this with default container. There are containers which support something like that, for example Autofac allows [Adding Registrations to a Lifetime Scope](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope).

If you are not willing to change the container used the workaround would be quite simple - use some kind of scoped abstraction to set and read the user info. For example:

```
interface IUserManager
{
    public MyUserInfo User { get; set; }
}

class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    private MyUserInfo? _user;

    public MyUserInfo User
    {
        get => _user ?? throw new Exception("User is not set");
        set
        {
            if (_user is not null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("User was already set");
            _user = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And set the user at scope start:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserManager>();

public class MyConsumer
{
    // ...
    public void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {
        var userInfo = new MyUserInfo { UserId = myMessage.UserId };
        using var scope = _sp.CreateScope();
        var um = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserManager>();
        um.User = userInfo;
    }
}
```

And then use `IUserManager` in `MyService` to provide the info to the repo.

Also you can split the `IUserManager` into 2 interfaces (so you can expose different things in different parts of app) and register it something like that (with some changes to the implementation):

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager>();
services.AddScoped<IUserSetter>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager>());
services.AddScoped<IUserGetter>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager>());
```

Comment: ok i think i understand. i was trying to think of how ASP.net does it, where it depends on the HttpContext, which is some weird kind of static, (I guess in .net 6 it's not actually static anymore though) but wasn't sure how i could replicate that functionality.

I will try to implement this, thanks!!

Comment: @DLeh yes, HttpContext is not a static in .NET Core.