# Is there a way to Dynamically add a scope depending on a parameter value using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I want to dynamically add Add a Scope depending on the User Input.

I have using WebAPI and I have a **CustomMiddleware** Inside the my CustomMiddleware, the invoke method has the following code

```
 public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
 {
     // Extract the accountingId from the route parameters.
     string accountingSystemTypeId = context.Request.RouteValues["accountingSystemTypeId"]?.ToString();


     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountingSystemTypeId))
     {

         using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
         {
             scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Func<string, IAccountingUserService>>()(accountingSystemTypeId);
}
}

StartupHelpers.AddService<IAccountingUserService, QuickBooksApiServices.AccountingUserService, XeroApiServices.AccountingUserService>(services);

internal static void AddService<TInterface, TQuickBooksImplementation, TXeroImplementation>(IServiceCollection services)
   where TInterface : class
   where TQuickBooksImplementation : class, TInterface
   where TXeroImplementation : class, TInterface
 {
     services.AddTransient<Func<string, TInterface>>(serviceProvider => accountsystemTypeId =>
     {
         if (new Guid(accountsystemTypeId) == AccountingSystemTypes.QuickAccountingSystemTypeId)
         {
             return serviceProvider.GetService<TQuickBooksImplementation>();
         }
         else
         {
             return serviceProvider.GetService<TXeroImplementation>();
         }
     });
 }
```

Depending on what the value of accountingSystemTypeId  is, I want to add a scope.

and in my startup.cs file, I have the following code

the method AddServices, looks like this

In theory, I thought this would work but for some reason, the scope never gets added dynamically.
I don't want to add if else statements everywhere in my controller, that is why I thought it'd be possible to do it this way.

What am I do wrong, and is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: What scope should be added where? Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: @GuruStron 

when I am dealing with Xero, I want the Xero implementation to be added in services.AddTransient<IAccountingUserService, QuickBooksApiServices.AccountingUserService>(); and when I am dealing with Quickbooks, I want the Quickbooks to be added             services.AddTransient<IAccountingUserService, XeroApiServices.AccountingUserService>();


And all this depends on the accountingSystemTypeId  which is provided by the user

Comment: You can't add dependency after the container was build

Comment: @GuruStron how would you approach my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Build-in dependency container [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement) child scopes and/or extension at runtime. Unless you are willing to switch to 3rd party one (like Autofac, it has something similar) you will need to implement something similar manually.

One way would be to just resolve the func were it is needed and pass the `accountingSystemTypeId` as parameter to the places where the resolution will happen (i.e. from the controller through all the services).

Another option is to create custom interfaces like `IAccountSystemManager` and `IAccountingUserServiceProvider` (both scoped):

```
interface IAccountSystemManager
{
    public string AccountSystemId { get; set; }
}
```

And use them something like this:

In middleware:

```
async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    // Extract the accountingId from the route parameters.
    var manager = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAccountSystemManager>();
    manager.AccountSystemId =  context.Request.RouteValues["accountingSystemTypeId"]?.ToString();

    // ...
}
```

```
class AccountingUserServiceProvider : IAccountingUserServiceProvider
{
    private readonly Func<string, IAccountingUserService> _factory;
    private readonly IAccountSystemManager _accountSystemManager;

    public AccountingUserServiceProvider(Func<string, IAccountingUserService> factory, IAccountSystemManager accountSystemManager)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _accountSystemManager = accountSystemManager;
    }

    public IAccountingUserService GetAccountingUserService() => _factory(_accountSystemManager.AccountSystemId);
}
```

And then resolve `IAccountingUserServiceProvider` where `IAccountingUserService` is needed.

Also check out a similar one - [Add a value to use within a scope in C# dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77197319/2501279)